# Node.js app.post for passport-local signup form not working

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to setup passport local sign-in but the form doesn't do anything when submitted.

My app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var credentials = require('./credentials.js');
app.use(require('cookie-parser')(credentials.cookieSecret));
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({extended: false}));
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
var passport = require('passport');
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.disable('x-powered-by');

var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:'main'});

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.post('/login', function(req, res){console.log("body parsing", req.body)});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});
```

The form html at /login for sign-ins:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I fill in username and password nothing prints out into the console from the post request. What do I have wrong?

Comment: Please review http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that removing this AMP js script solves the issue. For some reason it breaks the post requests.

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to serialize and deserialize the user details to make the user authenticated.

Here's and example.

**services.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');

//serialize and deserialize
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

//middleware
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    password: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, email, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user has been found'));
        }

        if (!user.comparePassword(password)) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong Password.'));
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
}));

//custom function to validate
exports.isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

and once you do the serializing, you have to actually apply the process to the router. i.e, make the user details enter passport.

In your router file:

```
const passportConfig = require('services.js');
```

Then you can simply access the data via `req.user`

Comment: I have tried copying the code from the passport documentation but I don't think my issue is there yet. I cut out most of the code in debugging and I guess the point I am at is why does this line not print anything when the form is filled out and submitted?
app.post('/login', function(req, res){console.log("body parsing", req.body)});